# Show last three entries before a specific one

Tags: django, datetime, django-filter

I have a django object named Entry that has a datetime field start

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get the last three entries that occured before a specific one. So if I have 7

1. 2014-05-23 17:00:00
2. 2014-05-23 20:15:00
3. 2014-05-25 18:00:00
4. 2014-05-26 16:00:00
5. 2014-05-28 17:00:00
6. 2014-06-10 18:00:00
7. 2014-06-12 16:00:00

for the 4th event I want to have the 3rd the 2nd and the 1st. In my view I do the following

```
def example_view(request,customer_id, entry_id):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=entry_id) #the specific entry
    former_entries = Entry.objects.all().filter(start__lte=entry.start, customer=customer).exclude(pk=entry_id).order_by('-start')[:3]
```

My thouhgt was get all the entries that are before the specific one. But If an entry exists at the same day exclude it from the query result. Then order them by start date and take the first three. ButI don't get the result I want. E.g for 6th event I get the 7th 5th and 4th. For 5th I get 7th 6th and 4th and so on. How can I correct my query? I am using `lte` so why does the 7th show up at my results when I the specific entry is the 6th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reverse the sort order, so that you're ordering by reverse start time.

Also, I'm not sure what your exclude is supposed to be doing. You want to get things that are *less* than the current item, so it seems more sensible to remove that exclude and just use `__lt` rather than `__lte`.

```
former_entries = Entry.objects.all().filter(start__lt=entry.start, customer=customer).order_by('-start')[:3]
```

Comment: I've corrected it and edited my post. As for the wrong results I was using entry as a variable in a for loop that changed results...Careless of me!